# How to add id sequence from select query in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I would like to add sequence id after I select data from more than one table

this is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.value_suggested_row, c.id as question_id, c.question, b.value
from survey_user_input_line a
LEFT JOIN survey_label b on b.id = a.value_suggested_row 
LEFT JOIN survey_question c on c.id = a.question_id
where survey_id = 6
ORDER BY question_id
```

and this is the result

[image: 1]

how to do the correct query to add the id sequence to the query so that the results are like this

[image: 2]

Can Anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the select list add ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY question_id) as id_sequence

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT @rownum:=@rownum+1 id_sequence, a.value_suggested_row, c.id as 
question_id, c.question, b.value
from survey_user_input_line a
LEFT JOIN survey_label b on b.id = a.value_suggested_row 
LEFT JOIN survey_question c on c.id = a.question_id
where survey_id = 6
ORDER BY question_id, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r;
```